# Why are these codes working differently in Python for loop list

Tags: list, for-loop, copy

I'm a beginner in coding but sometimes need to do it.
I want to make code that element is picked out temporarily in the list.
For example
[1,2,3,4] >>
[2,3,4] [1,3,4] [1,2,4] [1,2,3] like above
So I made some codes. But the results are different from my expectations.
For example below codes,
Only No3 is the same as my expectation.

1)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4] 
    c = [1,2,3,4] 
    for i in a: 
        b = c 
        b.remove(i) 
        print(b)
```

[2, 3, 4] [3, 4] [4] []

2)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4] 
    for i in a: 
        b = a 
        b.remove(i) 
        print(b)
```

[2, 3, 4] [2, 4]

3)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4] 
    for i in a: 
        b = [1,2,3,4] 
        b.remove(i) 
        print(b)
```

[2, 3, 4] [1, 3, 4] [1, 2, 4] [1, 2, 3]

The reason why those code are working differently than i thought.
I hope you can give me an answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration in the for loop you are actually modifying c (b=c). "b" is not a new memory location, it's just pointing to the old list "c":

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> c = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> for i in a:
...     print (f'c: {c}') 
...     b = c 
...     b.remove(i) 
...     print(f'b: {b}') 
... 
c: [1, 2, 3, 4]
b: [2, 3, 4]
c: [2, 3, 4]
b: [3, 4]
c: [3, 4]
b: [4]
c: [4]
b: []
```

To solve this, you must create a copy of the original list "c":

```
>>> import copy
>>> 
>>> a = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> c = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> for i in a: 
...     b = copy.deepcopy(c) 
...     b.remove(i) 
...     print(b) 
... 
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
```

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment).

Comment: thank you very much. I'll check it in more detail

Answer (score 0):

The reason these code are working differently is because

1)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4] 
    c = [1,2,3,4] 
    for i in a: 
        b = c 
        b.remove(i) 
        print(b)
```

[2, 3, 4] [3, 4] [4] []

for this code

the variable "b" and "c" are linked (they are point to the same memory space), so anything you remove from the list "b" is also removed from the list "c"

2)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4] 
    for i in a: 
        b = a 
        b.remove(i) 
        print(b)
```

[2, 3, 4] [2, 4]

for this code

the variable "a" and "b" are also linked., so anything you remove from the list "b" is also removed from the list "a". But as you remove from the list "b" (which is linked to list "a") the items for the "for loop" are also affected.

3)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4] 
    for i in a: 
        b = [1,2,3,4] 
        b.remove(i) 
        print(b)
```

[2, 3, 4] [1, 3, 4] [1, 2, 4] [1, 2, 3]

for this code

the list [1,2,3,4] what assign to "b" in each iteration of the loop that why it worked

to assign a list to another list without linking it use

```
copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I'll check it in more detail